# Solving two non-linear equation with two unknown using R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following equations:

```
 |2x+4y-9|=54
 |5x-6y+14|=21
```

How do I solve these equations for **x** and **y**. I would like to solve these equations using R.

Comment: You could just drop the absolute values and solve it -- it's a system of two equations with two unknowns.

Comment: @josilber actually your suggestion will only give part of the solutions. If janak needs all solutions then he needs also to solve the ones with a minus sign instead of the absolute value. That's 4 sets of two equations with two unknowns

Comment: @RockScience. I just wanted to point out this, then I saw your comments. You are right I need all the solution of this equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
A <- matrix(c(2,4,5,-6),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
b <- c(54,21)

ex <- c(-9,14)

z1 <- solve(A,b-ex)
z2 <- solve(A,-b-ex)

z3 <- solve(A,c(-b[1],b[2])-ex)
z4 <- solve(A,c(b[1],-b[2])-ex)

z1;z2;z3;z4
```

Check if results are what is required

```
A%*%z1+ex
     [,1]
[1,]   54
[2,]   21
```

and so forth for the remaining variants

```
A%*%z2+ex
A%*%z3+ex
A%*%z4+ex
```

Addendum:

A more efficient way of solving the system of equations is

```
B <- cbind(b,-b,c(-b[1],b[2]),c(b[1],-b[2]) )

solve(A,B-ex)
```